# Convert wide dataframe to long dataframe with specific conditions and addition of new columns

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, data-science, data-preprocessing

I have a sample dataframe as shown below.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

NaN = np.nan
data = {'ID':['A','A','A','A','A','A','A','A','A','C','C','C','C','C','C','C','C'],
    'Week': ['Week1','Week1','Week1','Week1','Week2','Week2','Week2','Week2','Week3',
             'Week1','Week1','Week1','Week1','Week2','Week2','Week2','Week2'],
    'Risk':['High','','','','','','','','','High','','','','','','',''],
    'Testing':[NaN,'Pos',NaN,'Neg',NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN,'Pos', NaN, 
              NaN,NaN,'Negative',NaN,NaN,NaN,'Positive'],
    'Week1_adher':['Yes',NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN,'No',NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN],
    'Week2_adher':['No',NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN,'No',NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN],
    'Week3_adher':['No',NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN,'No',NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN]}
    
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data)
df1
```

The final dataframe has to be such that there has to be rows as many number of weeks for each participant. After conversion of week columns to rows, it should have its corresponding values.

Also, the number of notna values in 'Testing' column for each week for each participant should be added to the '#of test" values.

The final dataframe should look like the image given below.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Preprocess your dataframe by creating the two new columns then group by `ID` and `Week` and finally aggregate new columns:

```
df1['SurveyAdherence'] = df1.filter(regex=r'Week\d+_adher').eq('Yes').any(axis=1)
df1['#Tests'] = df1['Testing'].notna()

mi = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([df1['ID'].unique(), df1['Week'].unique()],
                                names=['ID', 'Week'])

out = df1.groupby(['ID', 'Week']) \
         .agg({'SurveyAdherence': 'max', '#Tests': 'sum'}) \

out = out.reindex(mi) \
         .fillna({'SurveyAdherence': False, '#Tests': 0}) \
         .astype({'SurveyAdherence': bool, '#Tests': int}) \
         .reset_index()
```

Output:

```
>>> df1
  ID   Week  SurveyAdherence  #Tests
0  A  Week1             True       2
1  A  Week2            False       0
2  A  Week3            False       1
3  C  Week1            False       1
4  C  Week2            False       1
5  C  Week3            False       0
```

Comment: Thanks for the elegant solution. What if I need the last row shown in the image as well. For ID 'C', Week3, which is not displayed here.