# Groupby on 2 columns and split a column into 2 columns with first 2 nonNa values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-science, data-processing

I have a sample dataframe as given below.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

NaN = np.nan
data = {'ID':['A','A','A','A','A','A','A','A','A','C','C','C','C','C','C','C','C'],
    'Week': ['Week1','Week1','Week1','Week1','Week2','Week2','Week2','Week2','Week3',
             'Week1','Week1','Week1','Week1','Week2','Week2','Week2','Week2'],
    'Risk':['High','','','','','','','','','High','','','','','','',''],
    'Testing':[NaN,'Pos',NaN,'Neg',NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN,'Pos', NaN, 
              NaN,NaN,'Negative',NaN,NaN,NaN,'Positive'],
    'CloseContact': [NaN, 'True', NaN, NaN, 'False',NaN, NaN, 'False', 'True', 
                    NaN, NaN, 'False', NaN, 'True','True','False', NaN ]}
    
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data)
df1
```

Now, 2 columns have to be created CC1 and CC2. For each ID, for each week(important), CC1 will get the first non null value of 'CloseContact' column and CC2 will get the second non null value of 'CloseContact' column.

The final dataframe should shoild look like the image shown below.

[image]

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: @anky I did delete a question yesterday, but it was not answered. I am sure of it. I deleted the question because I figured out the solution to it. And coming to this question, I have not pasted the 'try code' only because it is just a part of a very big code and this just a sample. I have filtered everything out, and have just asked what I am stuck on.  Really sorry if anything wrong has been done, has occurred without my knowledge.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69456263/15239951):

```
mi = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([df1['ID'].unique(), df1['Week'].unique()],
                                names=['ID', 'Week'])

out = df1.loc[df1['CloseContact'].notna()] \
         .groupby(['ID', 'Week'])['CloseContact'] \
         .apply(lambda x: x.head(2).tolist()) \
         .apply(pd.Series).rename(columns={0: 'CC1', 1: 'CC2'}) \
         .reindex(mi).reset_index()
```

Output:

```
>>> out
  ID   Week    CC1    CC2
0  A  Week1   True    NaN
1  A  Week2  False  False
2  A  Week3   True    NaN
3  C  Week1  False    NaN
4  C  Week2   True   True
5  C  Week3    NaN    NaN
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution. I have figured out most of it. It was getting the 2 non null values I was stuck on. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

NaN = np.nan
data = {'ID': ['A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C'],
        'Week': ['Week1', 'Week1', 'Week1', 'Week1', 'Week2', 'Week2', 'Week2', 'Week2', 'Week3',
                 'Week1', 'Week1', 'Week1', 'Week1', 'Week2', 'Week2', 'Week2', 'Week2', 'Week3'],
        'Risk': ['High', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', 'High', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''],
        'Testing': [NaN, 'Pos', NaN, 'Neg', NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, 'Pos', NaN,
                    NaN, NaN, 'Negative', NaN, NaN, NaN, 'Positive', NaN],
        'CloseContact': [NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, 'False', NaN, NaN, 'False', 'True',
                         NaN, NaN, 'False', NaN, 'True', 'True', 'False', NaN, NaN]}

df1 = pd.DataFrame(data)

df = df1.groupby(['ID', 'Week'])['CloseContact'].apply(lambda x: x[x.notnull()].values[0:2]).reset_index()
df[['CC1','CC2']] = pd.DataFrame(df.CloseContact.tolist(), index= df.index)
df.drop(columns=['CloseContact'], inplace=True)
print(df)
```

Original DF:

```
   ID   Week  Risk   Testing CloseContact
0   A  Week1  High       NaN          NaN
1   A  Week1             Pos          NaN
2   A  Week1             NaN          NaN
3   A  Week1             Neg          NaN
4   A  Week2             NaN        False
5   A  Week2             NaN          NaN
6   A  Week2             NaN          NaN
7   A  Week2             NaN        False
8   A  Week3             Pos         True
9   C  Week1  High       NaN          NaN
10  C  Week1             NaN          NaN
11  C  Week1             NaN        False
12  C  Week1        Negative          NaN
13  C  Week2             NaN         True
14  C  Week2             NaN         True
15  C  Week2             NaN        False
16  C  Week2        Positive          NaN
17  C  Week3             NaN          NaN
```

Final Output:

```
  ID   Week    CC1    CC2
0  A  Week1   None   None
1  A  Week2  False  False
2  A  Week3   True   None
3  C  Week1  False   None
4  C  Week2   True   True
5  C  Week3   None   None
```

Comment: Thanks for the elegant solution. However, this does not print the rows where both the values are 'NaN'.

Comment: Working fine for me. If I set closecontact in row 1 as NaN it returns None None for (A, week1) group which is the desired result

Comment: @Muhammadhassan. You missed the `(C, Week3)` that does not exist in the original dataframe. You have to create a multiindex to reindex the dataframe. Although the answer is incomplete, you deserve a +1.

Comment: @Corralien thanks for the appreciation but I still don't understand the problem, I added a dummy row for week 3 and its working fine as shown in the output

Comment: The OP wants the product of 'ID' and 'Week'. However, there is no 'C, Week3' in the original data so at the end of your operation, the row 'C, Week3' does not appear.

Comment: Oh now I got it, thanks for the insight